# How to login to AWS Redshift as an IAM user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have an existing cluster, and an IAM user named 'dba-admin' with full permissions to manipulate it.

I successfully generated temporary credentials generated from the CLI:

```
aws redshift get-cluster-credentials --cluster-identifier db --db-user dba-admin --duration-seconds 7200
```

However, when I go to the query v2 editor, and try and login:

[image]

I get the following error: `FATAL: user "IAM:dba-admin" does not exist; [SQL State=42704]` before I can enter the password.

[image]

I have not manually created a Redshift user named dba-admin, in my understanding this is unnecessary?

Any ideas as to the issue?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you will need to add --auto-create flag, in order for the user to be automatically created. *get-cluster-credentials* will return the database user name prefixed with IAM: if AutoCreate is False or IAMA: if AutoCreate is True